# CSS - dynamically calculate width

Tags: css

I come across `width: calc(25% - 20px + 5px);`

I couldn't find any answer via google. I wanted to know how to get the width to be 410px for three boxes in each row, because right now it returns me 4 boxes in smaller width than 410px.

Any help or insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Protip for googling ^^: "[mdn calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)", "[site:webplatform.org calc](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/functions/calc)". Other useful resources for properties you've never heard of: http://caniuse.com (with compatibility and links to resources) and obviously here on SO

Comment: Maybe you don't need to use CSS3 calc. [box-sizing FTW](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) (also [box-sizing on CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method resolves the entire expression into a single value and then applies that to the element.

The thing you're trying to do would first calculate the `25%` of the parent element as an integer value and then it would move on to the next operand. Then would calculate the result and will apply.

I think, you need to lessen down the parent element's width property. Then you'll see three checkboxes with a width of 410px.

Secondly, you can also try to make sure the expression is accurate while calculating the result for the width.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/D6sQ5/ To see, how `calc()` method works.

Comment: thanks. so it takes the width of the parent element and then if i want 3 boxes with 20px gutters, it would be calc(100%/3-20)?

Comment: Yes, every element if provided with a percentage value uses the parent element's property. Similary, calc will first look for parent element's value and then do the math on it. I would like to advice you to use, `calc(100% / 3)` for width, and `margin-left: 20px` for gutter. :)